# How to change Activity title when a tab changes (SlidingTabLayout)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have searched for like three days for a solution for this. I have tried a lot of methods but I couldn't get it right. (Or maybe I am doing something wrong where).
So, what I am trying to do is change the Activity title to the current tab name, each time I change the tab, the activity title should change too.

So I have a MainActivity where I have 3 Tabs and 3 different fragments for the tabs. Here the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;                    
    private ViewPager mPager;                   
    private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;             

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);             
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);              
        mPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);         
        mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Custom ViewPager for the tabs
    class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        String[] tabsTitles;
        String vpPager;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabsTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabTitles);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //if (position == 0){
            //    news_fragment news_fragment = new news_fragment();
            //    return news_fragment;
            //}
            if (position == 1){
                login_fragment login_fragment = new login_fragment();
                return login_fragment;
            }
            else if (position == 2){
                about_fragment about_fragment = new about_fragment();
                return about_fragment;
            }
            else {
                news_fragment news_fragment = new news_fragment();
                return news_fragment;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabsTitles[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

}
```

And I am using this [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)

Comment: are you done or still its pending?

Comment: Pending. "Surender Kumar"'s answer did fix the title part but it created a new problem. The indicator does not move anymore >.<. So its still pending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one :

```
viewpager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        actionBar.setTitle(tabsTitles[position]);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Wow, This one works. But there is a little problem now. The indicator and the tab color does not change to the current tab anymore. It stays stuck at the first tab. Can you tell me how I can fix that?

Comment: change viewpager.setonchnagelistener to mTabs.setonchnagelistener

Comment: Awesome, I used mPager before, and thats the reason why the indicator got stuck. Thank you buddy ^_^. You saved me from a lot of headaches and time. Thank you everybody from this awesome site. ^_^

Comment: This is now deprecated. use mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener instead

Answer (score 0):

When you change activity. Firstlt `onCreate` method run. So in you `onCreate` get `ActionBar` and set its title.

**EXAMPLE**

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setTitle("title");
```

**Note** : Change `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()` if you are using the support library for `ActionBar`.

Comment: This solution gives a static title to the activity. (Which I already have). What I want to happen is the title to change when ever the tab changes.
Thank you for the answer though :-). Think you can suggest something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too:

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ....
    Toolbar toolbar;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Toolbar toolbar) {
        ...
        this.toolbar = toolbar;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        toolbar.setTitle(getPageTitle(position));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This solution causes an app crash. 
Error: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

"throw new RuntimeException("Main thread loop unexpectedly exited");". 
Thank you for the answer though :-). Think you can suggest something else?

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom action bar in your activity by inflating some layout like(After Oncreate):

```
    android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    bar.setCustomView(R.layout.homescreen_actionbar);
```

Take a TextView in your custom layout and in the onresume method of your fragment fetch its id using getactivity(), and set your title and iit will be working fine.